# General visit visa Validity time

Tags: visas, uk, nepali-citizens

can I enter uk before 2 month of my visit visa  expire? This is my first visit and I am nepali citizen.

Comment: Yes, if it's your first visit, that's fine

Comment: As long as you don't enter before your visa validy starts you should be fine.

Comment: Is there a reason you think you can't?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a valid visa, a valid passport, evidence of funds to support yourself while there, and an exit flight/bus/train/boat, there's very little reason to think they won't let you in.

In terms of the visa, as long as it's still within the validity period, it won't be an issue.